# How to get payload from jwt strategy?

Tags: node.js, jwt, nestjs, nestjs-jwt

I have jwt strategy:

```
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, "jwt") {
    constructor() {
        super({
            ignoreExpiration: false,
            secretOrKey: "secret",
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([
                (request: Request) => {
                let data = request.cookies['access'];
                    return data;
                }
            ]),
        });
    }

    async validate(payload: any){
        return payload;
    }
}
```

and this is my controller:

```
export class AuthController {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

    @UseGuards(AuthGuard("jwt"))
    @Get()
    getPayload() {
        //here I need to get the payload that was returned in jwt strategy
    }
}
```

So how can I get the payload in controller that was returned in jwt strategy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the value returned/resolved by `JwtStrategy#validate` will be the value of `req.user`

```js
import { Req } from '@nestjs/common'
// ...
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard("jwt"))
    @Get()
    getPayload(@Req() req: any) {
       console.log(req.user)
    }
```

https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#login-route